# custom export freeform data with radio buttons

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am trying to create a custom "download to csv" form for specific forms.

The radio buttons are saved in the db as 
287|~|Person 1, 290|~|Person 2, 296|~|Person 3

I want to create a custom download to csv form because I only want users to be able to download specific forms, not all.

I believe I need to use $this->multi_item_values($array)
but I'm pulling my dat from a query and the code below is not working

```
        $editors = $results->row('EDITORS');
        $updEditors = $this->multi_item_values($editors);
```

When I echo $updEditors, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Functions::multi_item_values() in /www/eh14243/apps_html/ctrl/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code on line 97

Thanks in advance for any help or pointing me in the right direction.

Peter T

Comment: Where are you getting this multi_item_values function from? Also, is this in a template, or an add-on of some sort?

Comment: Got it from the Freeform documentation (http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/fieldtype_development/#helper_functions).  I am using the code in a php enabled template that sends an email notification.

Comment: The code I'm referring to actually is for checkboxes but radio button code does look similar "Image|~|Image search request"